# How do I get the formatted value of one column in another column in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

How do I get the formatted value of one column in another column in jqgrid.

For eg:

```
{ name: 'amount', index: 'amount', sorttype: "float", formatter: processAmount, title: false },
{ name: 'netAmount', index: 'netAmount', sorttype: "float", formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) 
{
     // How do I get the formatted value of column "amount" here?
} 
}
```

I know that I am posting very little of my requirement or code. But I hope this is sufficient. Please let me know if you need more information on anything.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom formatters will be called before the body of the grid will be placed on the page. So you can't access the formatted value of one column inside of custom formatter of another column. What you can still do is *calling of another formatfer*. For example you can call `processAmount` function inside of formatter of `netAmount` column.

Comment: oh ok. I thought so. Custom formatting done here is a little complex and somehow I thought not to call that again.

Comment: Thanks for the information above Oleg. This was some way of achieving a bigger task. I have posted the bigger task as a different question. I really wish that you have some time to look into that as well. Any thoughts would be very welcome and highly appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274570/sort-a-custom-formatted-column-in-jqgrid